# Hotkey (RegisterHotkey) working, but overwriting Keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

I am trying to implement HotKeys to my Application.
I used a Class called "ClickerHotkey", which has information about my HotKeys stored in.
For example:

- List of all Additional-Keys that need to be pressed to trigger the Key,
- A Method, checking if all Additional-Keys are pressed
- VirtualKey for the actual Trigger-Key that sends a Message to the HwndSourceHook
  -> The Problem occurs here!

My HwndSourceHook:

```
//Hotkey set in other function:
//Key[] keyArray = {Key.D, Key.S};
//bool test = u32.RegisterHotKey(new ClickerHotKey(windowHandle, 0, keyArray));


//HotKey Handler
private IntPtr HwndHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            // ClickerClass used, if Message is "WM_HotKey"
            ClickerHotKey hKey;
            const int id = 0; // ID is set for now, for Testing Purposes
            
            if (msg != (int)u32.WindowsMessage.WM_HOTKEY)
            {
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            switch (msg)
            {
                // Hotkey Pressed:
                case (int)u32.WindowsMessage.WM_HOTKEY:

                    switch (wParam.ToInt32())
                    {
                        // Hotkey.ID = 0
                        case id:

                            // HotKey not existing
                            hKey = ClickerHotKey.GetKey(id);
                            if (hKey == null) 
                            {
                                handled = true;
                                break;                                
                            }

                            // Checks if all Additional-Keys are Pressed
                            if (hKey.AllKeysPressed())
                            {
                                // Do Stuff....                                
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                handled = true;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    break;                
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
```

Here is my Problem:
The Key works, but there are 2 issues:

1. I need to have all additional Keys pressed, before pressing the actual Trigger-Key
2. If i use D as Trigger and A as an additional Key, I won't be able to type D anymore as long as the Application is running

I know, that my first problem occurs because the HotKey only fires if I pressed the set Virtual-Key.
My problem is the second part. I also tried to use KeyListeners instead...

Comment: what about keybindings?
Set you class to be the datacontext and use keybindings in you XAML window

Comment: alos if the hot key does not exsist you still set the handled to true, it should be false in this case so it can bubble up and trigger somewhere else

Comment: @DenisSchaf Thank you for your reply.
I was still testing with how to handle, thanks for your help :D
Problem about using keybindings: I need those shortcuts to be global...
I am trying to create an AutoClicker for practice.
I was able to do something similar as I wanted using another Thread just checking if all the Keys are pressed, maybe i'll change my code to not use "RegisterHotKey" anymore.

Comment: with "Global" I meant: The key needs to be activated from any Point and window, not just some active, focused grid from my xml-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't been able to find a real "solution" to my question, but I guess a workaround does fine too.

As my HotKey needs to be accessible outside of the program's window, I've created a small test, this also just works fine using just a Thread listening for the specific Key-Combination:

...

```
namespace WpfAppKeyTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private static Key[] keyArray = {Key.F7, Key.LeftCtrl};
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Task KeyListener = new Task(listenForKeys);

            InitializeComponent();
            KeyListener.Start();
        }

        // A method, which executes some code once Keys pressed
        private void listenForKeys()
        {
            // Cancellationtoken for handling, you may have to pass the token into the method as a parameter
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            while (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Dispatcher is used here to check the Keyboard, as this only seems to work in Mainthread. Also executes Code, if needed.
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    if (allKeysDown())
                    {
                    
                        // Code here
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        // Simple Method checking the state of the passed Key-Combination
        private bool allKeysDown()
        {
            bool value = true;
            foreach (var key in keyArray)
            {                
                if (!Keyboard.IsKeyDown(key))
                {
                    value = false; break;   
                }
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

...